# Embed link into string and then display string (with link_to and gsub!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's what I'm trying to do. It's intended to replace plain text with a clickable link

```
<%= r.text.gsub!("\##{ht[:text]}", link_to("\##{ht[:text]}", "www.url.com")) %>
```

Where r.text is a string. But when it displays, the HTML is embedded in the text, it is not a link.

```
Some text <a href="www.url.com">Some other text</a>
```

How do I make it display the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use html_safe, i.e. `some_string.html_safe`.  Just make sure that the rest of the content is safe to display, being stripped of any other potentially malicious html.  So you for your specific case, you'd do this:

```
<%= r.text.gsub!("\##{ht[:text]}", link_to("\##{ht[:text]}", "www.url.com")).html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `<%= raw(r.text.gsub!("\##{ht[:text]}", link_to("\##{ht[:text]}", "www.url.com"))) %>`

Comment: No luck. I'm getting the same output.